# Calling component method in template while v-foring the component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using vuejs2. I want to create a method in my component and then call it to bind a class to it, but I can't get it to work. This is what I want to accomplish more or less, where getMachineClass() ideally would be a method in my machine component.

```
<machine
      v-for="item in machinesList"
      v-bind:key="item.id"
      v-bind:machine="item"
      v-bind:class="item.getMachineClass()">
</machine>
```

I know I can just put the method in my vue instance and then call it like this:

```
v-bind:class="getMachineClass(item)
```

I would like the method to be just in the component though. What can I do about it?

Machine component:

```
Vue.component('machine', {
        props: ['machine'],
        template: '#machine',
        data: function () {
            return {
                translations: translations,
                options: options
            }
        },
        mounted: ...
});
```

Comment: Dont know why you would like to do it that way...  but you make it work by using scoped slots.... can you show your machine component code

Comment: Added. Well, I thought it was a good idea since the logic for determining the class depends on the machine (so the item in machinesList).

Comment: i was curios about the template

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind the `class` on the root element of your machine component

```
//machine component template
<script type="text/x-template" id="machine">
    <div v-bind:class="getMachineClass(machine)">
     //...
    </div>
</script>
```

Since you are receiving the iterated item as a `machine` prop, pass it to the `getMachineClass` method